# Vote to close or delete?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

I asked a (what I believe to be...) duplicate question that someone's answered, and I'm presented with the choice of voting to close or delete it.

[image: delete an answered question?]

By "choice", I mean that it looks like I risk my question privileges by doing so. So I voted to close.

What's the real risk to my question privilege here?

Here's the question in question, [Performance of behaviorally identical conditional checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235950/performance-of-behaviorally-identical-conditional-checks)

Comment: Just close as a dupe- Then it can be a signpost to the other question and help future users who search and hit your question first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd vote to close as a duplicate if it is one. A closed question should be less detrimental to your question asking privileges. It's also the correct action, since a closed duplicate provides a link to the original question and answers.

Looking through your questions, I see none that have been closed, deleted, or even downvoted in the past. With nearly 1500 reputation, you shouldn't have anything to worry about.